# Вопрос по архитектуре WEB API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но решил кое что добавить и подробнее описать. Я делаю свое WEB API, чтобы примерно понять и научиться технологии. Никаких требований от кого то нет, я сам все придумываю, поэтому что то может казаться не логичным.
Я просто хочу научиться правильно строить архитектуру приложений.
Теперь опишу само WEB API. Я решил что сделаю API по работе спорткомплекса. Есть сущности, и с ними манипуляции разные.
Изначально я делал так: папка с самими сущностями (моделями), затем класс доступа к БД, папка репозиториев, которые как раз таки общаются с БД и производят манипуляции с данными. Репозитории отдельно под каждую используемую сущность. Затем я создал папку сервисов, в них так же интерфейсы, и классы их наследующие. Вот сервисы я уже делал так: "Допустим админ регистрирует тренера, значит я создаю сервис админа, в нем уже метод создания тренера, который использует репозиторий сущности Тренер". Правилен ли такой подход? Или под каждую сущность так же отдельный сервис? И нужны ли вообще сервисы? Контроллеры я создавал по такому же принципу, но мне объяснили, что нужно отдельно под каждую сущность свой контроллер, который использует уже сервисы. Кто нибудь объясните правильно ли я делал, или нет, и что нужно исправить. Вот примеры.
Сущность Администрартор:

```
public class Administrator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Репозиторий администратора (класс):

```
public class AdministratorRepository : IAdministratorRepository
{

    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public AdministratorRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Administrator> Create(Administrator administrator)
    {
        _context.Administartors.Add(administrator);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return administrator;
    }

    public async Task<Administrator?> Delete(int id)
    {
        var deleteAdministrator = await GetById(id);
        if (deleteAdministrator == null)
            return null;

        _context.Administartors.Remove(deleteAdministrator);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return deleteAdministrator;
    }

    public async Task<List<Administrator>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _context.Administartors.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Administrator?> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Administartors.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task<Administrator?> Update(UpdateAdministratorDto request)
    {
        var admin = await GetById(request.Id);
        if (admin == null)
            return null;

        admin.Name = request.Name;
        admin.Surname = request.Surname;
        admin.DateOfBirth = request.DateOfBirth;
        admin.PhoneNumber = request.PhoneNumber;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return admin;
    }
}
```

Сервис админа (класс):

```
public class AdministratorService : IAdministratorService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IAdministratorRepository _adminRepository;
    private readonly ICoachRepository _coachRepository;
    private readonly ISectionRepository _sectionRepositroy;
    private readonly ISubscriptionRepository _subscriptionRepository;

    public AdministratorService
    (
        IMapper mapper, 
        IAdministratorRepository adminRepository, 
        ICoachRepository coachRepository,
        ISectionRepository sectionRepository,
        ISubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository
    )
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _adminRepository = adminRepository;
        _coachRepository = coachRepository;
        _sectionRepositroy = sectionRepository;
        _subscriptionRepository = subscriptionRepository;
    }

    public async Task<ResponseAPI<GetSubscriptionDto>> CreateSubscription(CreateSubscriptionDto request)
    {
        var response = new ResponseAPI<GetSubscriptionDto>();
        try
        {
            var subscription = _mapper.Map<Subscription>(request);
            await _subscriptionRepository.Create(subscription);
            response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetSubscriptionDto>(subscription);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Data = null;
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = ex.Message;
            return response;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ResponseAPI<List<GetSubscriptionDto>>> GetAllSubscriptions()
    {
        var response = new ResponseAPI<List<GetSubscriptionDto>>();
        try
        {
            var subscriptionList = await _subscriptionRepository.GetAll();
            response.Data = subscriptionList.Select(s => _mapper.Map<GetSubscriptionDto>(s)).ToList();
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Data = null;
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = ex.Message;
            return response;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ResponseAPI<GetAdministratorDto>> RegisterAdmin(RegisterAdministratorDto request)
    {
        var response = new ResponseAPI<GetAdministratorDto>();
        try
        {
            var administrator = _mapper.Map<Administrator>(request);
            var user = new User
            {
                Username = request.Username,
                Password = request.Password,
                Role = "Administrator"
            };
            administrator.User = user;
            await _adminRepository.Create(administrator);
            response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetAdministratorDto>(administrator);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Data = null;
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = ex.Message;
            return response;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ResponseAPI<GetCoachDto>> RegisterCoach(RegisterCoachDto request)
    {
        var response = new ResponseAPI<GetCoachDto>();
        try
        {
            var section = await _sectionRepositroy.GetByName(request.SectionName);
            if (section == null)
                throw new Exception("There is no section with the given name");

            var coach = _mapper.Map<Coach>(request);
            var user = new User 
            { 
                Username = request.Username, 
                Password = request.Password, 
                Role = "Coach" 
            };
            coach.User = user;
            coach.Section = section;
            await _coachRepository.Create(coach);
            response.Data = _mapper.Map<GetCoachDto>(coach);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Data = null;
            response.Success = false;
            response.Message = ex.Message;
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Контроллер администратора:

```
public class AdministratorController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAdministratorService _service;

    public AdministratorController(IAdministratorService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpPost("register/administrator")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseAPI<GetAdministratorDto>>> RegisterAdmin(RegisterAdministratorDto request)
    {
        var response = await _service.RegisterAdmin(request);
        if (response.Data == null)
            return BadRequest(response);
        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpPost("register/coach")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseAPI<GetCoachDto>>> RegisterCoach(RegisterCoachDto request)
    {
        var response = await _service.RegisterCoach(request);
        if (response.Data == null)
            return BadRequest(response);
        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpGet("subscription")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseAPI<List<GetSubscriptionDto>>>> GetAllSubscriptions()
    {
        var response = await _service.GetAllSubscriptions();
        if (response.Data == null)
            return BadRequest(response);
        return Ok(response);
    }
    
    [HttpPost("subscription")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseAPI<GetSubscriptionDto>>> CreateSubscription(CreateSubscriptionDto request)
    {
        var response = await _service.CreateSubscription(request);
        if (response.Data == null)
            return BadRequest(response);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо того, чтоб создавать дубликат, нужно было отредактировать старый вопрос. SO не форум, помните это, SO это база вопросов и ответов на них, где вопрос должен быть полезен не только вам, но и будущим читателям. Создавая дубликаты, пользы "базе" вы не приносите, учитывайте это. Что касается вопроса - вы меня в тот раз проигнорировали, чтож, скажу еще раз - у вас есть "Маша", "Петя", "Коля" - будете для каждого создавать свой API? Аналогично и роли "Администратор", "Тренер", "Посетитель" - разные API?

Comment: Не путайте роль с API методом. Администратор - это роль человека, его права, по которым уже смотрится, может он вызвать тот или иной метод, или нет. А вот методы, это уже структура вашего проекта, она должна быть понятной всем. Вот условно "Админ регистрирует тренера", ок, вот вам допустим API `/gym/staff/add`, то есть у нас есть объект Gym (спортзал, если сайт сразу про него, то это можно убрать, лишнее), далее Staff (сотрудники), далее Add (добавить), отправляем туда POST, готово, новый сотрудник. Хотим список - `/gym/staff`, хотим конкретного `/gym/staff?id=001`, ну и так далее.

Comment: То есть, вы должны оперировать конкретными объектами, которые описывают конкретно вашу структуру проекта. По вашей логики, ваш API будет выглядеть условно так `/gym/вася/add` (если прям ваш код разбирать, то `administrator/register/administrator`, `administrator/register/coach` и т.д.), ну согласитесь, странно. Почему мы "Васе" что-то добавляем? Почему мы администратору что-то регистрируем? Не логично, верно? А если у нас еще и будет новая роль, то вы будете обязаны создавать новый метод, когда как это может быть одним методом. Короче, суть надеюсь уловили..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ блин, надо разбираться, не совсем в голове еще укладывается. У вас не будет какого нибудь примера с открытым кодом, чтобы я посмотрел наглядно... И да, в целом разделение на репозитории-сервисы-контроллеры это правильно? И сервисы получается по контроллеры делать.

Comment: Вы смешали все в одну кучу. API - это, по сути, ООП, вот как вы простыми классами опишете ваш спорткомплекс? Наверно, у вас будет сам класс комплекса, у которого будут некоторые свойства и методы, например, будет свойство "Сотрудники" (отдельный класс), которое будет содержать в себе всех сотрудников комплекса и иметь внутри методы и свойства связанные именно с сотрудниками, вот все это аналогично и в API, где у вас есть объект со своими методами и свойствами, ничего нового.

Comment: Контроллер - это как, скажем так, стартовая точка, где вы ловите нужный запрос, и что-то с ним делаете. Сервис - это отделенная логика, которая отвечает за одну конкретную задачу (например, сервис погоды, выносите все методы в отдельный класс, регистрируете в контейнере, вызываете где надо). Нужно вам это или нет, зависит только от вас и вашего проекта, в мелких проектах разделять код из 5 строк смысла нет, а в больших да, микросервиснаяструктура и все в этом духе. Примеры - не дам, извиняйте, у меня их попросту нет.